# Detect a CSS-only update in Codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codepen

In Codepen, with the Auto-Updating Preview feature enabled, upon editing the CSS pane, Codepen redraws the preview pane after a small delay. This is not news. However, it does not seem to reinit your javascript unless there is an edit to the javascript pane. Therefore: **when you make a CSS-only change, JS does not re-execute.** I want a JS listener to detect when there is an update to CSS which redraws the screen.

I started by listening for XHR requests, which is achievable, however I realized that it's not the request I need to listen for, it's the Response.  Well really, it's DOM update that occurs as a result of some JS callback *after* the XHR Response is received and processed. And because the preview pane looks to be encapsulated inside an iframe, I'm not sure if my executable javascript even has access to detect an update like this--I'm not certain how Code Pen is processing these changes.  Maybe the better question is, how do I detect an iframe screen redraw?  Not sure. But here's a non-working* snippet to illustrate what i'm trying to achieve:

*Try editing the CSS `p {color}` value in this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaPvYJ and observe that the rgb text value doesn't update to match.*

Comment: It updates the color but not the text within the paragraph. (the js portion of his code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MutationObserver to watch the head tag so when they insert CSS you can call a function. 
https://codepen.io/WebNesting/pen/KGxPbZ

```
var setText = function() {
  $("p").text(function() {
    return $(this).css("color");
  });
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    setText();
  });
});

observer.observe($("head")[0], {
    childList: true,
});
setText();
```

Comment: Yep, this worked perfectly.  I figured mutation observer would probably be the answer, even though I've never worked with it before.  I wasn't sure if the iframe scope would pose problems.  But it looks like it works without a hitch, here.  Thank you for the quick answer, @Jross!